# GPU for new notebooks by default

Tags: google-colaboratory

Whenever I create a new notebook (File - New python 3 notebook),
I have to set Hardware accelerator to GPU (Edit - Notebook settings).

How can I get rid of this routine?

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of an existing notebook that has the GPU setting enabled using File -> Save a copy in Drive.

Comment: and then use file - open notebook? If there's a lot of notebooks, imo it easier to use file - new